# Why is the data I update from a service not reflecting in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app I have a function that is updating an object with setState. I pass the data to another component with props and I make a console.log.

```
console.log(workingHours, workingHours.monday.startHourMonday);
```

in the first dump the object working hours have the values

```
{
"monday": {
    "startHourMonday": "9:0",
    "endHourMonday": "19:0"
},
"tuesday": {
    "startHourTuesday": "9:0",
    "endHourTuesday": "19:0"
},
"wednesday": {
    "startHourWednesday": "9:0",
    "endHourWednesday": "19:0"
},
"thursday": {
    "startHourThursday": "9:0",
    "endHourThursday": "19:0"
},
"friday": {
    "startHourFriday": "9:0",
    "endHourFriday": "19:0"
}
```

}

but the problem is for the key monday

```
{
    "startHourMonday": "",
    "endHourMonday": ""
}
```

the dumped values are empty.

the function that is updating the data

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
const workingHoursData =  (response) => {


    return  response.map( el => {
        workingHours.monday = {startHourMonday:el.startHourMonday, endHourMonday:el.endHourMonday};
        workingHours.tuesday = {startHourTuesday:el.startHourTuesday, endHourTuesday:el.endHourTuesday};
        workingHours.wednesday = {startHourWednesday:el.startHourWednesday, endHourWednesday:el.endHourWednesday};
        workingHours.thursday = {startHourThursday: el.startHourThursday, endHourThursday:el.endHourThursday};
        workingHours.friday = {startHourFriday:el.startHourFriday,endHourFriday: el.endHourFriday}
    })


}


useEffect(() => {
    try {
        apiOperations.getData("configs").then(response => {
            setResponse(response.data)
        }).catch(e => {
            props.history.push(adminLogin);
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

}, [])

useEffect (() => {
    workingHoursData(response);
},[response])
```

somebody know why?

Update:

the problem is I set direct the states values in the object.
I must use setState function.

Comment: please create codesandbox.io so that we can help you faster

Comment: When the initial render happens `response` will be empty and workingHoursData will be passed the empty array that `response` initially has.  However, once apiOperations completes, workingHoursData will be called again with a (hopefully) populated response.

Comment: JSON is a text format, so unless your code involves string manipulation, there's no JSON involved except extremely briefly when your `apiOperations`' `getData` function parses the data that comes back from the service.

Comment: You're not returning anything here `response.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate state for working hours and record the response right there. Also I wrote shorthand for formatting your resposne to what you need.

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
const [workingHours, setWorkingHours] = useState({})
const weekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wendesday', 'thursday', 'friday'] 

const upperFirstLetter = (word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)

useEffect(() => {
    try {
        apiOperations.getData("configs").then(response => {
            setResponse(response.data)
        }).catch(e => {
            props.history.push(adminLogin);
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}, [])

useEffect (() => {
    const formatResponse = weekdays.reduce((obj, day) => ({
        ...obj, 
        [day]: {
            startHour: response[`startHour${upperFirstLetter(day)}`],
            endHour: response[`endHour${upperFirstLetter(day)}`]
        }
    }), {})
    setWorkingHours(formatResponse);
},[response])
```

I think, there is no reason to name `startHourMonday` because `monday.StartHourMonday` is a little bit wordy, but if you need to create exatcly this field, simply replace

```
startHour: response[`startHour${upperFirstLetter(day)}`]
```

with

```
[`startHour$(upperFirstLetter(day)}`]: response[`startHour${upperFirstLetter(day)}`]
```